# Rails form_for password_field helper doesn't populate current password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
 <%= form_for @user, url: user_path do |f| %>
     <p>
        <%= f.label :password, 'Password:' %><br>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
     </p>
```

I would like the current password to be populated in the password field automatically so that when the @user's information is edited, the request will not fail due to having an empty password.

When using 'text_field', this field does get populated automagically, but password_field seems to disable this ability.

Comment: Are you using any authentication library (devise, etc)?  Then the password is never stored in plaintext, and thus, cannot auto populate a field.

Comment: Hi JTG, I'm using attr_encrypted to store secrets. Thus, @user.password will give the decrypted password. This is just a POC app - not meant to be in production. Like I said, if it's text_field it will auto populate, but password_field it won't - how do I change this behavior?

Comment: Have you ever found out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value of the password field manually. Rails hides the value for security reasons.

```
<%= f.password_field :password, value: f.object.password %>
```